# How to use a Button click to pass row ID to Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an Edit button in a dynamic table when click i would like to pass current row id to a Modal which is on the same page as the button I am having difficulty do this because this is all new to me I saw some examples with Ajax, JS and Jquery. I also look at pass threads on stackoverflow but some how I just cant seem to fully understand how to show/pass the ID into to Modal Body.

```js
$('.EdSubmit').click(function() { // edit button assist to pass ID
  var editID = $(this).attr('data-ROW-ID');
  $('#myModal .modal-body').html(editID);
});
```

```html
<input type='submit' value='edit' class='btn btn-secondary EdSubmit' name='EdSubmit' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' data-ROW-ID="<?echo $row['Cus_id'];?>">
```

Comment: Using inspect element, can you see if the data-ROW-ID attribute is there?

Comment: If you add `console.log($(this).attr('data-ROW-ID'));` does it display it in the console?

Comment: @TheCodesee When i try i get <?echo $row['Cus_id'];?> in console

Comment: Is that what it shows as the attribute for data-ROW-ID? Try changing your code to `data-ROW-ID="<?php echo $row['Cus_id']; ?>"`

Comment: Youre missing the starting `<?php` tag before `echo`

Comment: @TheCodesee Thank you so much :) Solved

Comment: Thank you @AnuragSrivastava

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace `<?` with `<?php`. It might also work if you add a space between `<?` and `echo`

```
<input type='submit' value='edit' class='btn btn-secondary EdSubmit' name='EdSubmit' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' data-ROW-ID="<?php echo $row['Cus_id'];?>">
```